# Is it allowed to compare a pointer to an object to nullptr?

Tags: c++

I have declared and implemented two classes, `Library` and `Book`. `Library` has a private member `Book** books`. This pointer to a pointer is used to store pointers to `Book` objects. I have also overload the `+=` operator in the `Library` class as follows:

```
Library& Library::operator+=(Book* addThisBook){
    bool added = false;
    int index = 0;

    if(isFull()){
        cout << "Library is full!" << endl;
    }else{
        //add book in first available space
        while(!added && index<librarySize){
            if(books[index] == nullptr){
               books[index] = addThisBook;
                added = true;
            }
            index++;
        }  
        numBooks++;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

My question is in regards to the conditional in the if statement; is it allowed to compare a pointer to a custom class to `nullptr`?

Comment: It is allowed, but make sure that your library (`books[index]`) is indeed initialized to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is it allowed to compare a pointer to a custom class to `nullptr`?

Yes, a pointer of any type can be compared to `nullptr` for (in)equality.

Comment: Also, all pointers have an implicit conversion to boolean that does the check (ptr != nullptr), so OP could write `if(!books[index])` instead